# App fails to install on HoneyComb

Tags: android, android-3.0-honeycomb, android-package-managers

I've just tried installing my app onto my Motorola Xoom and having problems with the install.

When I install the APK on device and try to start application it crashes with following message.

> The application Package installer (process
>   com.android.packageinstaller) has stopped unexpectedly. Please try
>   again

Application installs and run fine on both Emulator and Phone.I am installing application through laptop.

** Additional Info **

I've just found that it doesn't work on the Emulator now either if I start the app from the app list.; It reports 'Application not installed'.It does work though if I start it through Eclipse.

Manifest: (note I've removed my package name and altered Activity names)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      package="PACKAGE_NAME_REMOVED" 
      android:versionName="1.0.5" 
      android:versionCode="9">

    <uses-permission 
        android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE">
    </uses-permission>
    <uses-permission 
        android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE">
    </uses-permission>
    <uses-permission 
        android:name="android.permission.INTERNET">
    </uses-permission>
    <uses-permission 
        android:name="android.permission.BROADCAST_STICKY">
    </uses-permission>

    <uses-sdk 
        android:targetSdkVersion="8" 
        android:minSdkVersion="5" />


    <application 
        android:label="@string/app_name" 
        android:debuggable="false" 
        android:icon="@drawable/launchericon">

        <activity 
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name_beta" 
            android:launchMode="singleTop" 
            android:permission="android.permission.BROADCAST_STICKY" 
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" 
            android:configChanges="orientation">

            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name="MyListActivity"          
            android:label="@string/devicelistactivity_label" 
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" 
            android:configChanges="orientation">
        </activity>
        <activity 
            android:name=".interface.InterfacceActivity" 
            android:permission="android.permission.BROADCAST_STICKY" 
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" 
            android:launchMode="singleTop" 
            android:configChanges="orientation">
        </activity>   
    </application>
</manifest>
```

Comment: Can you please post the logcat?

Comment: Can you also post your manifest?

Comment: Is the APK a signed release APK? Did you change your signing keys?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears I was using permissions incorrectly. Logcat was reporting a security exception due to my app using stick broadcasts even though I had put stickybroadcast permission in the manifest.

As detailed [here](https://groups.google.com/group/android-developers/browse_thread/thread/5ce448ad766369a5), I removed the stickybroadcast permission from the activity and application nodes.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you get all the `Activity` name and path right. Clean and Build the project before export

Comment: Downvoted? Perhaps reason to justify the downvote would be nice.